# Two time series similarity with slightly offset timestamps

Tags: time-series, correlation

Let's say I have two time-series S1 and S2 where S1 looks like this:

```
Epoch timestamp |value
1492827582,      100
1492827782,      127
1492827982,      135
1492828082,      200
...              ...
```

and S2 looks like this:

```
Epoch timestamp |value
1492827133,      50
1492827333,      155
1492827533,      156
1492827933,      300
...              ...
```

What is the most straightforward method to produce some kind of similarity value? I am mainly interested in seeing how the growth is. Don't really care about the absolute values -- just want to have a sense of how similar the curve shapes are. Please note that the timestamps are slightly offset with a slightly different stepping but generally very close. I have heard about cross-correlation approaches but they seem like an overkill.

Thank you very much  for reading this!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on timeseries, not in finance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a good case to use [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution to me!